# What is the "Main Value of an Integral" (denoted as $\textbf{VP}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\phi(x)}{x}dx$ for $f(x) = \frac{\phi(x)}{x}$)?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, distribution-theory

The definition given to us is as follows (for $\text{supp }\phi \subset (-R, R)$ ):

$$\textbf{VP }\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\phi(x)}{x}dx = \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0^+} \: (\int_{-R}^{-\varepsilon}\frac{\phi(x)}{x}dx + \int_{\varepsilon}^R \frac{\phi(x)}{x}dx)$$

This is something we call the "Main Value of an Integral" (translated directly from Polish at least, "Wartość główna całki"). Here, we take the main value of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\phi(x)}{x}dx$

But what *is* this in the first place? How can I interpret this somehow (maybe on an example)? In what kind of topics and problems do we use this "main value of an integral"?

And most importantly: Is "main value of an integral" even the right translation (because I couldn't find anything on the Internet)?

Comment: In English, it would be "principal value", sometimes with Cauchy's name attached.

Comment: Ok, I see, thanks. And when do we use the principal value?

Comment: To replace [improper integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral) which do not exist due to asymmetric limits with integrals that do exist in the special case that the limits are taken symmetrically.  That is, when we want to ignore [odd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions#Odd_functions) singular behaviour.

Comment: [Wikipedia article on Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a [distribution](https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution), the [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) satisfies the equation $x \cdot \operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{x}=1$ and is almost the only such distribution. It is also the distributional derivative of $\ln|x|.$

Comment: What does it mean that "as a distribution, it satisfies the equation"?

Comment: @anon. What I meant was that the Cauchy principal value can be thought of in several ways. One of those ways is as a distribution, and this distribution satisfies that equation.

Comment: Yes, and my question is what does it mean that a distribution "satisfies" an equation?

Comment: @anon. It means that the distribution $x \cdot \operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{x}$ equals the distribution $1,$ i.e. that for every test function $\phi$ one has
$$\langle x\cdot\operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{x}, \phi(x) \rangle = \langle 1, \phi(x) \rangle.$$
This boils down to
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int_{|x|>\epsilon} \frac{x\phi(x)}{x} dx = \int \phi(x) \, dx,$$
which is quite obvious.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @md2perpe's accurate comments:

Yes, there is quite a bit of traditional muddle about this idea. Yes, we can "define" it... but, as you suggest, *why*? :)

Yes, this *functional* applied to a function does arise naturally in various settings. Both as a limit, and (up to constant multiple) as a Fourier transform of the rather innocent distribution the sign function. Yes, you will want to study a bit about "distributions" to be able to easily parse the explanations about the PV thing...

Indeed, a "principal value integral" is *not* a literal integral. Its behavior is not that of an integral... but is still sane, if one does understand "distributions".

In complex analysis, one occasionally finds a situation in which one is looking at a limit of contour integrals... where the limit would pass directly through a (for example) simple pole. Some sources pretend to "define" the integral through a pole as obtaining "half the residue". In fact, the idea that one can "define" such things into existence is inaccurate. Such a limit can be considered carefully (it's not even about "rigor", it's about getting the right answer!), and we have things like the Plemelji-Sokholski formula... (Eminently google-able.)

Yes, also, the PV integral is the unique (up to scalar multiples) functional on test functions on $\mathbb R$ that is odd and homogeneous of degree $-1$. There are various ways to prove this. A naive heuristic would make such a thing by the obvious integral... but that integral will not converge well. Certainly not absolutely, etc. Yes, it may seem that the PV convention is just one choice of many, but, in fact, we can prove uniqueness, to that particular description is necessarily equivalent to any other. :)

(That kind of uniqueness result is always very comforting to me: goofy constructions have made me uneasy... but by now I can understand that sometimes the construction (and, thus, proof of existence) is necessarily not-so-intuitive.)